# Why doesn't git.kernel.org repo have arcturus_gpu_info.bin file?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, firmware

I can not find file `arcturus_gpu_info.bin` from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu

I think the above URL is the official repo where to find such firmware file, why can't I find the required firmware file?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably because AMD haven't published it yet? AFAICT Arcturus GPUs haven't even been released.

Comment: @muru thank you very much for your reply. I didn't know that. I was just trying to get rid of all the missing firmware warnings when I upgrade my kernel. Maybe they can be ignored.